# Как realloc() освобождает память?

Tags: c, динамические-массивы

```
int len = 5;
double* array = malloc(sizeof(double) * len);

for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 1)
{
    array[i] = i;
}

len -= 2;
array = realloc(array, sizeof(double) * len);

for (int i = 0; i < len + 2; i += 1)
{
    printf("%.1f ", array[i]);
}
```

Как известно, free() очищает память и позволяет использовать её снова. Что делает realloc() в моём примере? Он не очищает ячейки памяти под бывшие индексы 3 и 4 массива (видно из вывода), но даёт ли он возможность использовать эти ячейки для других программ, как это делает free() ?

P.S. И как мне очистить выше названные ячейки: просто присвоить, например, 0?

Comment: tealloc вызывает внутри free и malloc по необходимости. Все остальное в вопросе какое-то странное и непонятное

Comment: как правило, выделяется память большими кусками (*страницами*) и вы можете безболезненно работать дальше чем попросили, но это называется неопределённое поведение. Если вы смогли изменить ячейки памяти без крушения программы, значит эта страница памяти ваша. Современные системы использует защищённый режим памяти, где процесс не может вообще прочитать не свою память.

Comment: Перечитал вопрос. Ответ прост все зависит от внутреннего устройства библиотеки. Она может просто оставить память на месте, ничего не освобождая - 3 дабла точно влезут туда, где были 5. Занулять память точно никто не будет - зачем делать дармовую работу. Специально их чистить не нужно, ну кроме free потом. Вы программируете на java/PHP/JavaScript?

Comment: @KoVadim
Нет, я на первом курсе, только недавно C начали изучать )
Занулять память, чтобы потом к этим данным не обратились "хакеры" )
Всё-таки не нашел ответа на мой вопрос в комментарии Вашем и выше. Переформулирую. Вот когда мы выделяем память с помощью malloc(длина=5), это значит мы резервируем какое-то кол-во памяти, т.е. какой-то другой malloc() уже не заберет себе эту выделенную память. Потом мы уменьшаем резервы памяти relloc(новая длина=3). Вопрос: может ли забрать себе память другой malloc() (или даже другой объект), которая отводилась под ДВА ПОСЛЕДНИХ дабла?

Comment: ответ прост - зависит от реализации рантайма. realloc может перевыделить меньшее кол-во памяти и освободить весь блок (который маллок выделил) и другие выделения памяти смогут его использовать. Второй вариант - realloc просто поментит, что памяти по указателю пользователь указал меньше, но саму память освобождать не будет. Она будет висеть. Другой malloc ее не будет использовать. Но и самому писать в эту память не стоит. Занулять можно, но лучше делать до вызова realloc.

Comment: грубо говоря память это как винчестер с фат таблицей. если вы удалили файл, то никто не будет обнулять данные. и резервирование памяти для другого файла создаст только адреса в фат таблице. данные будут видны из другого файла, правда на совсем другом адресе *смещении* файла. *это всё просто для понимания*

Comment: `free() очищает память` — [может не очищать](https://rextester.com/MJU38049). Аналогично, `realloc` может как очищать, так и нет. `но даёт ли он возможность использовать эти ячейки для других программ`. Если другие программы будут переиспользовать освобождённые ячейки памяти, то хранившиеся в этих ячейках значения буду очищены. Следить за изоляцией данных между приложениями — прерогатива операционной системы. [Пример](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18385556).

Comment: и ссылка на код с UB:) слово "очищает" применимо к free может значить две разные вещи. Как зануление памяти (или затирание), что обычно не происходит и не требуется, так и исключение памяти с списка "занятой приложением" (хотя тут нужно очень аккуратно - у нас есть ещё менеджер памяти и он не всегда отдает ОС всю память сразу).

Comment: Начиная с некоторого размера (у меня в `Linux avp-desktop 5.4.0-107-generic x86_64` это какое-то неочевидное число **133497 bytes**) `free()` возвращает память в ОС и доступ к ней вызывает `Segmentation fault`. Очевидно, что аналогичное поведение может быть и у **`realloc()`**. Поэтому, если указатель после realloc изменился, то обращений к ранее выделенной памяти следует избегать

Comment: в любом случае обращение к памяти, которая была освобождена (неважно, free, realloc) - неопределенное поведение. Приложение может работать, может падать, может быть ещё тысячи разных вариантов.

Comment: Раз уж речь зашла о неопределённом поведении, то нужно иметь ввиду, что нельзя использовать не только высвобожденную память, но и исходный указатель, если он где-либо хранится. Вызов `realloc` делает невалидным переданный ему указатель и все указатели, указывающие на любой участок той памяти, которая подверглась перераспределению с помощью `realloc`. Даже если возвращаемый `realloc` указатель побитово не отличается от исходного, даже если запрошенный `realloc`'ом размер не отличается от исходного, то исходный указатель всё равно нельзя использовать. [Пример](https://rextester.com/WBRFE59038).

Comment: да, старый си был ближе к ассемблеру:) а в новом это все не работает, зато компилятор может творить чудеса, иногда даже в плане оптимизации.

Answer (score 1):

Решил тут написать про то, что узнал (прошу прощения, если где-то ошибаюсь).

Допустим мы выделили память "маллоком" под "интовый" массив длины 3. Его ячейки условно: 100, 104, 108.
При уменьшении выделяемой памяти (допустим длина стала 2), доступные нам ячейки таковы: 100, 104.

108 же отправляется в "свободное плавание", т.е. будет доступна под другие нужды программы.
При увеличении выделяемой памяти (допустим длина стала 4), доступные нам ячейки могут быть таковы: 100, 104, 108, 112 - ЕСЛИ ЕСТЬ ВОЗМОЖНОСТЬ РАСШИРИТЬСЯ ИМЕННО ТАК, т.е. 112 доступна. Если же 112 не доступна, то realloc() может перенести начальный адрес на ДРУГОЙ, т.е. доступные нам ячейки могут стать такими: 600, 604, 608, 612.

100, 104, 108 отправятся в "свободное плавание".
ПРИЧЕМ, данные ячеек, которые отправляются восвояси, могут быть не удалены (зависит от компилятора).

З.Ы. Помогло видео - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zuegQmMdy8M&t=12533s. Конкретно часть про динамическую память.